# macro to find the top level form containing the form

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to access the top level form with a macro? Something to the effect of:

```
(defmacro which-defn []
     ....)

(defn hello []
  (which-defn))

(defn world []
  (which-defn))

(hello) => 'hello
(world) => 'world
```

Comment: Came up empty so far, though a macro has access to the special &env var during compile time, which gives you access to local bindings.

Comment: Does it have to be a macro? Could forcing & catching an error and inspecting the stack trace be something to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This function](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.198/api/tupelo.misc#fn-info) already exists in [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  You don't need a macro:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.misc :as misc]))

(defn hello []
  (misc/fn-info))

(dotest
  (is= (hello)
    {:class-name  "tst.demo.core$hello",
     :file-name   "core.clj",
     :method-name "invokeStatic",
     :line-num    6,
     :ns-name     "tst.demo.core",
     :fn-name     "hello"}))
```

Comment: This won't do you any good if you want to use it at macroexpansion time.

Comment: I would have preferred a macro but this works for me. thanks!